# How are the linear differential operator equations are solved in perturbation theory?

Tags: operators, perturbation-theory, s-matrix-theory

I have a problem in solving the first order linear differential equation:

[image]

where U<sub>o</sub> and H<sub>o</sub> are [n x n] matrices and |i>  is a [n x 1] column vector. The author states that by considering a complete set of states at t= -∞ , this can be converted into an operator equation

[image]

which will then imply :

[image]

What is the meaning of complete states and how can the methods of O.D.E be applied to matrices in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide all the context, so I am guessing a bit here.

Loosely speaking, a complete set of states $\mid k\rangle$ would be such that any state $\mid\psi\rangle$ can be written

$$\mid\psi> = \int_k c_k \mid\! k\rangle d\mu(k)$$

where $\mu$ is some measure. In some cases, this would just be $\sum_k c_k \mid\! k\rangle$, but anyway, the point is that if you can then choose $\mid i\rangle$ to be any of the $\mid k\rangle$, and therefore, for any quantum state $\mid\psi\rangle$,

$$i\frac{d}{dt}U_0(t)\mid\psi\rangle = H_0U_0(t)\mid\psi\rangle$$

which means that the operators on the right and on the left must be the same:

$$i\frac{d}{dt}U_0(t) = H_0U_0(t) \tag{1}$$

Then you have to remember the definition of the exponential as a series. That works for matrices too, not only for real numbers:

$$\exp tA = \sum_{p=0}^{+\infty} \frac{t^p A^p}{p!}$$

But then you can easily see that you have

$$\frac{d\exp tA}{dt} = A\exp tA$$

This relation is true for the exponential series whatever kind of arguments is in the series. This why you get the solution you quoted. I mean, we know there is an unique solution, so if we find one, and we have with the series, then it must be the one! Since $\lambda U_0(t)$ is a solution if $U_0(t)$ is a solution, we can actually more generally write that

$$U_0(t) = U_0(0) e^{-itH_0}$$

The essential bit here is that $H_0$ does not depend on time of course.

Comment: I understand how we get the solution in this case as here H0 and U commute with each other and H0 is time independent.But what if you could not come up with a guess? I was asking for a general method of solving ODEs that involve matrices. I can't always conjure up the unique solution. As we have integrating factors elsewise, do we have something similar in this case? Also what should be the solution if Ho and U don't commute?

Comment: We do not need to postulate that $H_0$ and $U_0$ commute: this come as a corollary of the form of the solution. Unless I am missing something… As for the integrating factor, I edited my answer.

Comment: As for the case when $H_0$ is time-dependent, in the general case, we can't say anything but if $H(t)$ and $H(t')$ commute for any $t$ and $t'$, then $\exp \int_0^t H(t) dt$ is the solution.